# Trigger Storyboard on TextBlock Visibility.Visible

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm brand spanking new to WPF and XAML, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question:

I am trying to start a StoryBoard on a TextBlock that changes the text. I want to start this animation when the TextBlock becomes visible. It looks like the only events you can trigger inside of a TextBlock.Triggers bracket is an EventTrigger. If this is so, as far as I can see an EventTrigger needs a routed event, but IsVisibilityChanged isn't one. Since I can't use that, any ideas as to what I should do instead?

I have attached a sample of my code that isn't working (doesn't compile), just to illustrate what it is that I am trying to do:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" Text="Payfast Running" Name="AnimatedTextBlock">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)"
                            Duration="0:0:1.5"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTextBlock"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running." KeyTime="0:0:0:5"/>
                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running.." KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running..." KeyTime="0:0:1:5"/>
                        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Lastly, I need to do this in markup, not CodeBehind, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to wrap that all up into a style.

```
    <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" Text="Payfast Running" Name="AnimatedTextBlock">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="Visible">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)"
                                        Duration="0:0:1.5"                                       
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTextBlock"
                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running." KeyTime="0:0:0:5"/>
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running.." KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Payfast Running..." KeyTime="0:0:1:5"/>
                                    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                               </Storyboard>
                           </BeginStoryboard>
                       </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
     </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it put me on the right path. The thing I was missing was that I had to wrap it up in a style as you said. Once that was done I was able to use a property trigger to achieve the desired result.
Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

"I want to start this animation when the TextBlock becomes visible."

You could bind your `TextBlock`'s `Visibility` to a `boolean` property (note that you have to add a resource for boolean-to-visibility conversion):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=ReadyToPlay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
```

And then, in your `ReadyToPlay` property's setter method, you could add an `if` statement that checks for whether or not to start your `Storyboard`:

```
if (value) {
    // start Storyboard:
    // find Storyboard instance and call Begin() method on it
}
```

By doing this, when `ReadyToPlay` becomes `true`, the `TextBlock` will become visible and the `Storyboard` will begin simultaneously.